# Transformation Matrix to Taper an Object

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

What would the 4x4 transformation matrix be to taper an object along an axis by a given value?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, such transformation cannot be performed by matrices.

Comment: yeah I was imagining it wouldn't be possible, but hoped I was wrong. Thanks for the confirmation.